# Eclipse | Packge turns into a directory, breaks my whole project

Tags: java, eclipse, directory, package

So the issue i am having is extremely weird. When i have a preexisting project set up (and am moving it from computer A to computer B). I make a new project and import it the normal way. It is very, very package based and there are around 30-40 packages. Two packages are made into directories instead of packages.

For example, instead of org.project1.tools.stuff it is org/project1/tools/stuff.

I have checked the code, at the top it goes package org.project1.tools.stuff and then the imports and so on.

Since it is in a directory listing and NOT in my actual packages, it is severely breaking my entire project.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The normal way being exporting to an archive file then importing again?

Comment: No, just taking the whole project (excluding the project file for eclipse). And hitting new java project then choosing the root folder containing the src, that way it auto builds it

Comment: If you are just moving the project from one computer to the other, I would do that.

Comment: the problem is that the original project is on a comnputer i don't own anymore, and i have the files just from a flash drive. So any computer i have tried has had the same result :|

Comment: what the hell? It fixed itself when i deleted the project from my eclipse package explorer and added it again >.>

Answer (score 5):

If you right click on your project, select properties->Java Build Path. On the subsequent screen you can specify which folders are source folders.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just deleted the project and added it again without touching the files. O.o